# AutoRollback doesn't rollback

Tags: scala, specs2, scalikejdbc

After I run the following spec, the table exists. I expected it to never be present as it should only exist within the eventually rolled-back transaction.

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import scalikejdbc.{DB, NamedDB}
import scalikejdbc.specs2.mutable.AutoRollback

class MyQuerySpec extends Specification with ArbitraryInput {

  sequential

  DBs.setup('myDB)

  "creating the table" in new AutoRollback {
    override def db(): DB = NamedDB('myDB).toDB()
    private val tableName = s"test_${UUID.randomUUID().toString.replaceAll("-", "_")}"
    private val query = new MyQuery(tableName)

    query.createTable
    ok
  }
}
```

The line `DBs.setup('myDB)` is not part of the examples. But if I remove it I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool is not yet initialized.(name:'myDB)`

The source of `MyQuery.create`:

```
SQL(s"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tableName").execute().apply()
SQL(s"""
     |CREATE TABLE $tableName (
     |  id               bigint PRIMARY KEY
     |)""".stripMargin).execute().apply()
```

Config:

```
db {
  myDB {
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    url = "****"
    user = "****"
    password = "****"
    poolInitialSize = 1
    poolMaxSize = 300
    poolConnectionTimeoutMillis = 120000
    poolValidationQuery = "select 1 as one"
    poolFactoryName = "commons-dbcp2"
  }
}
```

ScalikeJDBC v2.2.9

Comment: try set `autoCommit="false"` or `defaultAutoCommit="false"` in connection properties.

Comment: It seems like `defaultAutoCommit="false"` has worked. Thank you. Will confirm in full after a good night's sleep. *yawn*

Comment: I was wrong. It didn't work. It was only that the schema list didn't update in IntelliJ when I checked. Sorry.

Comment: Can you try same with DML operation (replace create table to insert data), just to make sure that it's problem of scalikejdbc.

Answer (score 1):

The `MyQuery#createTable` must accept implicit parameter like this:

`def createTable(implicit session: DBSession)`